# Iterating through nested objects to get single property from each

Tags: c#, recursion

I have the following object

```
public class WorkShift
{
    public int TotalVios {get; set;}
    public WorkShift NextWorkShift {get; set;}
}
```

I can have unlimited amounts of NextWorkShift objects deep, how would I get TotalVios from all of them combined starting at the root object all the way down? I feel like this should be really simple, but I don't think I can loop on this or anything like that, I almost need a recursive method of some sort?

What I am trying to accomplish is getting the TotalVios on all objects within that parent object. So basically I am looking for
int TotalViosForThisWorkShift;

It would be populated by going to the top object and adding to TotalViosForThisWorkShift, then going to the NextWorkShift within there and adding that TotalVios to TotalViosForThisWorkShift and then going to the NextWorkShift in there and adding that TotalVios  to TotalViosForThisWorkShift and so on and so on.

Comment: You don't need recursion to iterate a linked list, and in fact it's a poor solution because you risk blowing the stack. Having said that, you'll need to show a bit more of an attempt to avoid getting this closed as _too broad_. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the usage of the head and next in that question. I want to basically start at the top WorkShift object, get TotalVios, go to the NextWorkShiftObject add to TotalVios and so on and so on

Comment: @mameesh In the example, `head` is just the name of a variable of type `Node`. So in your example it could be `var head = new WorkShift();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write yourself a small extension method as following to parse the child nodes.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<WorkShift> EnumerateChild(this WorkShift source)
    {
        yield return source;
        var node = source.NextWorkShift;
        while(node != null)
        {
            yield return node;
            node = node.NextWorkShift;
        }
    }
}
```

And now you could retrieve all the TotalVios using

```
var result = rootNode.EnumerateChild().Select(x=>x.TotalVios);
```

If you need to the total Sum (from the update in the question), then you could use the IEnumerable.Sum() method

```
rootNode.EnumerateChild().Sum(x=>x.TotalVios)
```